# How to turn cable internet into Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, routing

I'm living in a house that has cable internet using RJ-45 cables. However, my computer doesn't have an entry for this type of cable. I would like to know if there's any solution that I can buy (like something that I can connect to the Internet that will give me Wi-Fi in my room).

Comment: Hi, I recommended migrating your question to superuser.stackexchange.com.  But I can tell you right now what you need to search for is this question: "how do I set up a wi-fi access point"?  You will find many many answers.

Comment: @JohnDeters - SuperUser might not want it because `any solution that I can buy` is a product recommendation.

Comment: @Vilican - true, but he could even google for "wifi access point" and come up with a thousand recommendations on Amazon.  It's just not a "security" question, that's all.

Comment: it's commonly called a router, and you can buy them anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your house's RJ-45 cables are running Ethernet, then Yes, any "wireless router" (a.k.a. Wi-Fi Access Point, wireless home gateway, etc.) with an RJ-45 Ethernet port will do.